# How to append values to a key using ini4j?

Tags: java, ini, ini4j

I want to append a value to following Key like this:

```
[Section]
Key=value1,value2
```

I tried Wini and Section getAll() and putAll() functions but it always replaces value1 with value2 instead of appending value2. And I did' t find any tutorial about this online. How can I do this using ini4j? Or another jni writinig and parsing library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally treated it as a single Key-value pair and appended to the string after "Key=".

Answer (score 0):

This topic is a little old, but I'm faced exact the same problem, so...

To read all:

```
//open the file
Ini ini = new Ini(new File(iniFileName));

//load all values at once
Ini.Section names = ini.get("mySectionX");
myStr[] = names.getAll("myKey1", String[].class);
```

To put all (with the same ini and names):

```
//if myStr[] have changes
names.putAll("myKey1", myStr);
```

At final you gonna have the ini file like this ("myKey1" is ALWAYS the same):

```
[mySectionX]
myKey1 = value1
myKey1 = value2
myKey1 = value3
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding more information,
if you want o create a new file:

```
Ini ini = new Ini();
ini.setComment(" Main comment ");  //comment about the file

//add a section comment, a section and a value
ini.putComment("mySectionX", " Comment about the section");
ini.put("mySectionX", "myKey1", "value1");

//adding many parameters at one in a section
String[] keyList = {value1, value2, value3};
ini.add("mySectionY");
Ini.Section names = ini.get("mySectionY");
names.putAll("myKey1", keyList);           //put all new elements at once
...
ini.store(new File(iniFileName));
```